# Can you help me check the contruction of Operator J'_1: H^1(Omega\Gamma) -> H^1(Omega) right or not? where Gamma is a curve in Omega

Tags: analysis, derivatives, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces, continuity

We suppose that  $\mathcal{H}= L^2(\Omega)$, $\mathcal{\widetilde{H}}= L^2(\Omega\backslash\Gamma) $ and $ \mathcal{H}_1=H^1(\Omega)$,  $\mathcal{\widetilde{H}}_1= H^1(\Omega\backslash\Gamma)$.
It follows that  $\mathcal{H}= \mathcal{\widetilde{H}}$ almost every where since $\Omega
= \Omega \backslash\Gamma $ almost everywhere.
We have linear operators

$J: \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{\widetilde{H}}$, $J':\mathcal{\widetilde{H}} \to \mathcal{H} $

$J_1: \mathcal{H}_1 \to \mathcal{\widetilde{H}}_1$, $J'_1: \mathcal{\widetilde{H}}_1 \to\mathcal{H}_1$.

Let $J=J'=Identity$ and $J_1= Identity$.

We define the operator $J'_1: \mathcal{\widetilde{H}}_1 \to\mathcal{H}_1$ by

(J'_1f)(x,y) =  {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{f(x,y), \quad if\quad (x,y) \in \Omega \backslash \Gamma }\\
{{\beta _0}\quad if \quad(x,y) \in \Gamma }.
\end{array}}

where $\mathop {\lim f(x,y)}\limits_{(x,y) \to ({x_0},{y_0})}  = {\beta _0}, \quad({x_0},{y_0}) \in \Gamma. $